# OpenFileDialog in Application Startup closing immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to load some files serialized by another project in my solution at application startup by doing this:
App.xaml.cs :

```
<Application (...)
         Startup="Application_Startup">
</Application>
```

Application_Startup method :

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        (...)
        if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("C"))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Settings.Default.SavedPath) && Directory.GetFiles(Settings.Default.SavedPath, "*.extension").Length == 0)
                // do sth
            else
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show("somerror", "Error!",
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.No, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    OpenUserConfig();
                else
                    Shutdown();
            }
        }
(..)
}
```

OpenUserConfig method :

```
private void OpenUserConfig()
        { 
var dial = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (dial.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) return;
            //do sth
        }
```

These two methods are in App class thus there is a problem :
messageboxes and filedialogs disapperar after a fraction of second after popuping them.
I menaged to find solution for messagebox ( by using MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) but I cannot sustain OpenFileDialog what should I do with this?
Also ( this might be important - I don't know): I have SplashScreen in my application.

Comment: A dialog always requires an owner window.  If you don't specify one explicitly then it goes looking for one.  If the owner disappears then the dialog is history as well.  The corollary is that it is in general a very bad idea to display a dialog when you don't have a stable window.  Like none at all or a splash screen.  Just wait displaying it until your main window is up and running.  With a File + Open command the boilerplate way to leave it up to the user.

Comment: @HansPassant That's very good answer to my question I created one more window and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant noted and based of my observations:
The splash screen closes when the application becomes idle, such as when a dialog opens.
Any `Window` that opens before `MainWindow` is ready tends to close when the splash screen closes.

You needed a file to be loaded before the user can interact with the `MainWindow`, I can see two ways:

- You can open a second `MessageBox` with some dummy text, and then open the `OpenFileDialog`

  ```
  private void OpenUserConfig()
  { 
      MessageBox.Show("Select file");

      var dial = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (dial.ShowDialog())
      {
          // Do something...
      }
   }
  ```
- Or what I ended up doing was running the setup code entirely from `MainWindow`, by copying nessesary information to public getters in `App` and subscribing to the `Window.Loaded` event

  ```
   private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (!(Application.Current as App).LoadedWithoutError)
       {
           var dial = new OpenFileDialog();
           if (dial.ShowDialog())
           {
              // Do something...
           }
       }

       IsEnabled = true;
   }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

You can create your own form with dialog and open this form. It is the fastest way.

Comment: The nature of the form is irrelevant.  What killed it was the fact that it accidentally got pinned to the splash screen.

Comment: @DonBoitnott is right, crearing another form didn't help at all.